# Создание magnet-ссылки

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Каким способом возможно сгенерировать magnet ссылку средствами PHP, зная адрес торрента?

Comment: Что такое «адрес торрента»? URI, по которому можно получить файл метаданных?

Answer (score 1):

Ах, да сущие пустяки - надо знать алгоритм, по которому генерируется ссылка на самом торрент-сайте =)

Comment: Ну ето скорее Ваши предположения, ведь в utorrent можно получить магнет ссилку имея торрнет файл. Я вотхеш незнаю как получить(